# How to ignore build ERRORS (and not warnings) in VS2017 SQL Database projects

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-data-project

I work on VS 2017 with SQL Database projects. After to have generate all scripts, I have some errors (71501 or 71561 -> unresolved references). I want to use SQL Database projects only to compare a database with versioned scripts, only to have an history of my database changes.

- I don't want to do database references because I don't need it and I've already tried it and it doesn't work with linked servers.
- I've already tried to set Build Action to None. But when I recompare my database with my scripts, existings scripts are ignored and the compare tool want add new scripts.

So, could you help me to find a simple way to ignore errors in SQL Database Projects in VS2017 ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I think that you can't do that, however SSDT works with the linked servers and you can get rid of the errors normally. Generate dacpac for the linked server, add it as a reference and use synonyms for  all external objects (the synonyms are not requirement, but it is very useful to use them in such cases)